# Launch App multiple times from a Pinned Shortcut

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

I have a CMD prompt shortcut pinned to the taskbar but I can only launch it once? 
So I have to have yet another icon on the desktop to launch multiple windows?
(The same thing applies to many app that I need to launch multiple copies of MsTSC / SSH etc.)

Answer (score 6):

Hold Shift while you click the pinned program.

This will open a new window of the app as opposed to activating the currently open window.

Comment: @user109575 Remember to click the checkmark next to this post to accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can launch new instances of pinned programs at the first 9 (or 10?) positions by pressing `Windows-Shift-N`, with N being the position from the left.

Comment: ooooh neeet!  I didn't know 'bout that one! ... except it wouldn't work for my long-list of pinned apps.  /sigh  too many windows...

Comment: two out of three aint Bad - But thank you for the response.
( Not that there's anything wrong with it - I'd just have to learn how to count ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can middle click any item on the taskbar to launch another instance.

Answer (score 2):

right-click click on the "Command Prompt" in the popup menu.   Tadaa... new command prompt.

Comment: Or, more generally, the menu item with the same name as the application.

Comment: Thank you also - Always more than on way to *Skin a cat*