# Launch multiple copies of a program pinned to Windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, multiple-instances, pin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Launch App multiple times from a Pinned Shortcut](https://superuser.com/questions/367984/launch-app-multiple-times-from-a-pinned-shortcut)

Using *Taskbar buttons* set as *Never combine* and the *Classic* skin (if that matters), how do I launch multiple copies of a program pinned to Windows 7 taskbar?

For example, I pin Notepad to the taskbar. Clicking it once opens one Notepad window. Clicking it again minimises the window. In earlier Windows with Quick Launch, each click on its Quick Launch icon opens a new window.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Right click on the icon and then you can click to launch it again.

Alternatively hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the icon to spawn another process.

Answer (score 4):

You can middle-click the pinned icon, but of course the app should support multiple instances.

Answer (score 3):

Just right click on the running program on taskbar and click on the name of application and it will open another instance for that program which is **pin in taskbar**.

[image]